# Left-aligning all text in itemized list (beamer)

Tags: beamer, lists, indentation, itemize

I'm trying to make an itemized list in beamer (using the [`beamerposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) package). By default, the text of first-level bullet points is left-aligned at the same point as non-list text, and the bullet actually comes before that. I want the bullet point to be aligned with or even further right from the non-itemized text, so I added a line to indent it (`\setlength` etc.):

```
\begin{block}{Evaluation}
    Compare seasonality estimated by our method with that in:
    \begin{itemize}
        \setlength{\itemindent}{1.5em}
        \item ``Agricultural" grid cells ($p_a > 0.8$) 
        \item ``Non-agricultural" grid cells ($p_a < 0.2$)
        \item 80\% threshold based on the land cover classification scheme for cropland discussed by \citep{Hansen:2000wm}.
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}
```

Here is a picture of the result:
[image: picture of the result]

Unfortunately, this solves one problem and creates another. The third item has to have a line break, and the text on the second line is not left-aligned with the rest of the itemized list text. How do I make it align?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try influencing the left margin instead of the item indent to get the alignment right. This can be done by changing the length `\leftmargini` *before* `\begin{itemize}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Evaluation}
    Compare seasonality estimated by our method with that in:
    \setlength{\leftmargini}{2.5em}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item ``Agricultural" grid cells ($p_a > 0.8$) 
        \item ``Non-agricultural" grid cells ($p_a < 0.2$)
        \item 80\% threshold based on the land cover classification scheme for cropland discussed by [10].
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output result]

Answer (score 1):

Imho the best solution is using the package enumitem and setting

```
\begin{itemize}[labelindent=\parindent,itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=*]
    \item ``Agricultural" grid cells ($p_a > 0.8$) 
    \item ``Non-agricultural" grid cells ($p_a < 0.2$)
    \item 80\% threshold based on the land cover classification scheme for 
          cropland discussed by [10].
\end{itemize}
```

Choose an appropriate value for the `labelindent` key, but always set `itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=*.` If you want to format all of your lists this way, use the `\setlist*` command to globally set your options:

```
 \setlist*[itemize]{labelindent=\parindent,itemindent=0pt,leftmargin=*}
```

Use the starred version since it won't override former settings. For explanation, see my answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184780/can-someone-please-explain-the-enumitem-horizontal-spacing-parameters/618036?noredirect=1#comment1543730_618036).