# How can I decrease the indent of itemize inside a column in Beamer

Tags: beamer, indentation, itemize, columns

I am using a package Beamer to create my presentation file. But I need to have some itemize information along with a table, in two different column. But the final shape is not good. I want to reduce the left indent of my itemize itmes. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
     \documentclass[slidestop,Liberation serif]{beamer}
     \setbeamercovered{transparent}
     \usecolortheme{lily}
     \usepackage{lmodern}
     \usepackage[english]{babel}
     \usepackage{mathrsfs}
     \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
     \usepackage{graphics}
     \usepackage{graphicx, color}
     \usepackage{subfigure}
     \usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
     \usepackage{booktabs}
     \usepackage{multirow}
     \usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

     \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}%[shrink=20]
    \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{6cm}
    \begin{itemize}%[leftmargin=0cm]
    \item text 1.
    \item text2.
    \item text 3.
    \item text 4.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \noindent
    \begin{column}{4cm}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{ A} & \textbf{ B} \\
        \midrule
        A1    & B1 \\
        A2    & B2 \\
        A3    & B3 \\
        A4    & B4 \\
        A5    & B5 \\
        A6    & B6 \\
        A7    & B7 \\
        A8    & B8 \\
        A9    & B9 \\
        A10   & B10 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{table}%
    \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your snippet is *nearly * a complete minimum working example, but not quite - could you tweak it just a little? Welcome!

Comment: Thank you, how can I tweak it :) would you please let me know , I am quite amateur in using latex and beamer.

Comment: It's easier to help you if your code starts with `\documentclass` and finishes with `\end{document}`. And being a `beamer` problem it's very useful to know which `beamertheme` do you use.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51410/1952

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `beamer` so apologies if there is some incompatibility I don't know about, but I have just been playing with the indents on the list environments in my article. I have loaded `enumitem` which allows you to control the size of various parameters in the list environments. I would think the following would do what you want (replace `\parindent` with whatever you want)

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=\parindent,labelindent=\parindent}
```

Comment: `beamer` doesn't like `enumitem`

Comment: @HarishKumar fair enough  - like I said, never used it myself. Should I just delete my answer do you think?