# How to draw this lines with tikzmark

Tags: tikzmark

I would like to draw lines to illustrate the lengths used with the package `enumitem` , so i create this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\quad

\vfill
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* -, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep= 1.5cm,itemindent=1cm]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{enumerate}
\vfill

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\coordinate (left) at ($(current page.west)+(1.5,0)$);

\draw[red]($(left)+(0,-1)$)--($(left)+(2,-1)$)%
   node[midway ,anchor=north]{\tiny leftmargin};
\draw[blue]($(left)+(3,-1.3)$)--($(left)+(2,-1.3)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=north]{\tiny itemindent};

\draw[red]($(left)+(0,0.5)$)--($(left)+(1,0.5)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=south]{\tiny labelindent};
\draw[blue]($(left)+(1,1)$)--($(left)+(1.5,1)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=south ]{\tiny labelwidth};
\draw[red]($(left)+(1.5,0.5)$)--($(left)+(3,0.5)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=south]{\tiny labelsep};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And we get

[image]

But this works only if we place list in the middle of the page, how can i improve this code with `tikzmark` so lines moves with the list , thanks.

Comment: How should the bottom red/blue labels behave if the itemized text is longer or shorter than you show, since they would otherwise interfere?

Comment: I tried using lengths `\leftmargin`, `\labelsep`,`\labelwidth`, `\labelindent`,`\itemindent` but i failed

Comment: lengths change outside of the `enumirate` environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) ibrary and the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package; the lengths will automatically adapt according to the `enumitem` settings used and will display the current value:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\showlabels#1#2{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red] 
  (current page text area.west|-{pic cs:#2}) --
    node[below,font=\scriptsize] {leftmargin=\the\leftmargin} 
  ++(\leftmargin,0);
\draw[blue] 
  ([xshift=\leftmargin,yshift=-\baselineskip]current page text area.west|-{pic cs:#2}) --
    node[below,font=\scriptsize] {itemindent=\the\itemindent} 
  ([yshift=-\baselineskip]{{pic cs:#1}|-{pic cs:#2}});
\draw[red] 
  ([yshift=3\baselineskip]current page text area.west|-{pic cs:#1}) --
    node[above,font=\scriptsize] {labelindent=\the\labelindent} 
  ++(\labelindent,0);
\draw[blue] 
  ([xshift=\labelindent,yshift=1.5\baselineskip]current page text area.west|-{pic cs:#1}) --
    node[above,font=\scriptsize] {labelwidth=\the\labelwidth}
  ++(\labelwidth,0);
\draw[red] 
  ([xshift=\the\dimexpr\labelindent+\labelwidth\relax,yshift=0.5\baselineskip]current page text area.west|-{pic cs:#1}) --
    node[above,font=\scriptsize] {labelsep=\the\labelsep} 
  ([yshift=0.5\baselineskip]pic cs:#1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* -, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep= 1.5cm,itemindent=1cm,align=left]
\item\tikzmark{a}text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\tikzmark{b}
\showlabels{a}{b} 
\end{enumerate}

\vskip3cm

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* -,labelwidth=60pt,leftmargin=4cm,labelsep=30pt]
\item\tikzmark{c}text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\tikzmark{d}
\showlabels{c}{d} 
\end{enumerate}

\vskip3cm

\begin{enumerate}
\item\tikzmark{e}text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\tikzmark{f}
\showlabels{e}{f} 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Simply place a mark immediately after `\item` using `\tikzmark{<name1>}` and another one right after the last word of the item using `\tikzmark{<name2>}` and then use `\showlabels{<name1>}{<name2>}`. The code needs three runs to stabilize.

Comment: Your answer is much better than mine.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Here, I don't use overlays, but just store the `tikz` parts in two macros (`enummetricsA` and `\enummetricsZ`), which are automatically called when invoking the `labelenumerate` macro.  Because the bottom "leftindent" label would run into the text if it were fixed relative to the top of the environment, I fix it relative to the bottom of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\def\enummetricsA{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (left) at ($(current page.west)+(1.5,0)$);
\draw[red]($(left)+(0,0.5)$)--($(left)+(1,0.5)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=south]{\tiny labelindent};
\draw[blue]($(left)+(1,1)$)--($(left)+(1.5,1)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=south ]{\tiny labelwidth};
\draw[red]($(left)+(1.5,0.5)$)--($(left)+(3,0.5)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=south]{\tiny labelsep};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\def\enummetricsZ{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\coordinate (left) at ($(current page.west)+(1.5,0)$);
\draw[red]($(left)+(0,-1)$)--($(left)+(2,-1)$)%
   node[midway ,anchor=north]{\tiny leftmargin};
\draw[blue]($(left)+(3,-1.3)$)--($(left)+(2,-1.3)$)%
   node[midway,anchor=north]{\tiny itemindent};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newenvironment{labelenumerate}
{\noindent\kern-2.1ex\smash{\raisebox{-1.1\baselineskip}{\enummetricsA}}\begin{enumerate}}
{\end{enumerate}\noindent\kern-0.9ex\smash{\raisebox{-.0\baselineskip}{\enummetricsZ}}}

\begin{document}
\quad

\bigskip
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* -, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep= 1.5cm,itemindent=1cm]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{enumerate}%

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* -, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep= 1.5cm,itemindent=1cm]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{enumerate}%

\begin{labelenumerate}[label=\arabic* -, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep= 1.5cm,itemindent=1cm]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{labelenumerate}%

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic* -, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep= 1.5cm,itemindent=1cm]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{enumerate}%

\begin{labelenumerate}[label=\arabic* -, leftmargin=2cm, labelsep= 1.5cm,itemindent=1cm]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{labelenumerate}%

\end{document}
```

[image]