# Giving indentation to the overflow item

Tags: indentation, itemize, overflow

I have this code

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\geometry{ left=25mm, right=25mm, bindingoffset=0mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm }
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemindent}{3.5em}
  \item Menggunakan dan mengoperasikan database PostgreSQL
  \item Merubah design interface email reservasi kedalam bentuk PDF menggunakan Thymeleaf
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And the result is this
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsuUw.png]

How can I give the indentation for that overflowing row?

Thank you!

**[Solution]**
Change itemize into enumitem

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\geometry{ left=25mm, right=25mm, bindingoffset=0mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm }
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=5em]
  \item Menggunakan dan mengoperasikan database PostgreSQL
  \item Merubah design interface email reservasi kedalam bentuk PDF menggunakan Thymeleaf
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site please post full minimal examples not sniplets. Your choice of preamble and document class often greatly affects the solution. Plus have a look at the `enumitem` package for easy list adjustment.

Comment: Thank you @daleif once I use enumitem, the identation is adjusted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add options to 'enumerate' in order to achieve this. Check this at the following link: [Enumitem: Indented list where new paragraphs are not indented](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217722/enumitem-indented-list-where-new-paragraphs-are-not-indented)

Comment: Thank you! I changed the itemize into enumitem, I'll add the solution above

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck :)