# Break the line in Latex

Tags: indentation

I want to write a sentence in Latex but since it is too long at a point  the lines breaks and it continues at the line below.

It is like that:

Which command can we use so that when the sentence continues at the second line it begins under "Hello" and not the beginning of the line?

[image]

PS: Before this proposition, there shouldn't be a number... How can this be done?

It looks like that:

[image]

Isn't it possible to put Για (the first word of the proposition ) at the same point of the second line as the point from the first line where the title begins?

I wrote the following to get this:

```
\Large \textbf{Πρόταση 1 } \par Για τον δακτύλιο των ακεραίων  \textlatin{p}-αδικών αριθμών $\mathbb{Z}_p, p \in \mathbb{P}$ ισχύουν τα εξής:
```

Comment: It's not obvious to me that you even want to use list environments - your question is not that clear, but it seems like you had some chat last night so perhaps others have a better idea. However, if you are using list environments, you should check out `enumitem` as @Werner suggests, and you might want to check out [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184780/can-someone-please-explain-the-enumitem-horizontal-spacing-parameters]

Comment: PS What's not clear is that in your question you are talking about a break in a sentence and controlling that indent, but in your example you are not breaking a sentence, you have a "title" and a following "sentence" on the next line...

Comment: You have *completely* changed the question. From a standard enumeration with a request for consistent indentation to setting up a theorem-like environment that removes indentation underneath it. This makes any old answers useless. My suggestions is that you revert the changes and ask a new/different question.

Comment: I have to agree with @werner. Due i have to admit that this was for a lack of knowledge at the time. Thats why i suggested http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20048465#20048465

Answer (score 1):

[image: evindaProposition]

If you know what should be on the page, you can print a line of
letters (or rather pixels) from the upper left corner to the
lower left corner, step to the right, print pixels downwards,
step to the right, print pixels downwards .... till the page is
typeset. Crappy for a human being. Humans like more structure.
You have given us a screenshot of the *pixel-approach* (a quite
blurry one i might add) and ask us to reproduce it. What is
important for us to know is the **structure**. You want to print
objects, lets call them *proposition* and want automatic
numbering, maybe refer to them later by `\ref{prop:daktulio}` and
want to be flexible to alter the visual appearance at one global
point.
Define a new environment for that. Or use one the many *theorem* packages, that is fine as well.

*But don't do it by hand every time.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{prop}
%\newcommand{\theprop}{\arabic{proposition}}
\newenvironment{prop}{\refstepcounter{prop}{\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}\Large\noindent\bfseries Proposition
\theprop}\par\noindent\ignorespaces\begingroup\color{blue}}{\endgroup\par\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{prop}
\blindtext
\label{prop:daktulio}
\end{prop}
\blindtext\color{blue} as we have seen in proposition \ref{prop:daktulio}
\end{document}
```

So, to finally answer your question, i think you are looking for `\noindent`. But if i one day see a `\noindent`  in between `begin{document` `\end{document}` you have to explain yourself.

Don't waste time doing the task by hand over and over again, if you can automate it within two minutes.