# Using custom item labels in itemize environment inside an `mdframed` box causes content to slip out of box?

Tags: lists, itemize, mdframed

Consider the following MWnotE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed} % noteboxes, boxes, etc.

\newmdenv{notebox}

\begin{document}
    \section{Cats}
        Here is an important theorem.

        \begin{notebox}
            Let $X$ be a graph with $k$ vertices. Then, the earth is flat.

            \begin{proof}
                It suffices to show that the following conditions hold: 

                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item[Closure.] 
                        \begin{equation*}
                            0/0 = 0
                        \end{equation*}
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{proof}
        \end{notebox}

\end{document}
```

It produces as output the following:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do use an `\item[Closure.]` there if you just have one singular item?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There are other items, but I have truncated them for the sake of the MWE.

Comment: Alright, but `\item[...]` is not always the best way to achieve such things

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am open to alternative suggestions. One thing I sometimes do is `\item Closure:` (as an example), so that I get the bullet point and the label.

Comment: I know what `\item Closure` will do ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not assuming knowledge (or lack thereof!) on your part, or whoever else reads this later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to `koleygr`'s idea, but using `labelsep=0pt` and automatic adjustement of `\leftmargin` with `leftmargin=*` from `enumitem` in conjunction with removal of the itemize label by `label={}`.

This could be done with a `\newlist` and `\setlist` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed} % noteboxes, boxes, etc.

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newmdenv{notebox}


\begin{document}
    \section{Cats}
        Here is an important theorem.

        \begin{notebox}
            Let $X$ be a graph with $k$ vertices. Then, the earth is flat.

            \begin{proof}
              It suffices to show that the following conditions hold: 

              \begin{itemize}[label={},labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
              \item Closure.
                \begin{equation*}
                  0/0 = 0
                \end{equation*}
              \item Foo

              \end{itemize}
            \end{proof}
          \end{notebox}

        \begin{notebox}[innerleftmargin=2cm]
            Let $X$ be a graph with $k$ vertices. Then, the earth is flat.

            \begin{proof}
              It suffices to show that the following conditions hold: 

              \begin{itemize}[label={},labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
              \item Closure.
                \begin{equation*}
                  0/0 = 0
                \end{equation*}
              \end{itemize}
            \end{proof}
          \end{notebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice... I could swear that tried this before... But probably had other options too that breaked it...  (+1)

Comment: @koleygr: Thanks (I've +1 for you some while ago, because you were just a few seconds faster than me with the same `leftmargin=40pt` idea. ;-)) -- Referring to the options of `enumitem`: Yes, that sometimes confuses me too as well

Comment: For more on enum item options you (or at least me :P) can look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184780/120578

Comment: @koleygr: Well, my statement was confusing: I rather meant that I forget the `enumitem` options rather quickly and are confused to use them in that case. You should have kept your answer, however

Comment: It was  clear what you mean... I just used it in a not elegant way in my answer  and added in the comment what I need to read... (If not the manual)... I don't think that my answer has to offer something... but I will undelete it if you think it has to offer to anyone...

Comment: @koleygr: A working solution is a solution!

Comment: Ok... Undeleted and made clear that I am a better "TeXpert" :P [PS: For these who have already read The TeXbook, TeXpert is a way to say that you haven't read it and that you can't even pronounce TeX the right way... ]

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: I could do it even better than @ChristianHupfer but did not wanted to make clear how much better I am :P ... So, just leaving this non elegant but simple way as a "working solution".**

A solution is to use `enumitem`'s `leftmargin` option, like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed} % noteboxes, boxes, etc.

\newmdenv{notebox}

\begin{document}
    \section{Cats}
        Here is an important theorem.

        \begin{notebox}
            Let $X$ be a graph with $k$ vertices. Then, the earth is flat.

            \begin{proof}
                It suffices to show that the following conditions hold: 

                    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=40pt]
                        \item[Closure.] 
                        \begin{equation*}
                            0/0 = 0
                        \end{equation*}
                    \end{itemize}
            \end{proof}
        \end{notebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But instead of using a fixed value (40pt), is it possible to put in some automatic document-dependent value?

Comment: @user89, It can be done... But in a difficult way because is deppends on the width of the the word "closure" or of the bigger word used... and this word comes in the code after the part that have to be given... This makes things somehow complicated and I suppose that Christian's suggestion is better and that you don't really need a hack that is too complicated to get a result that could take with other ways...

Comment: @koleygr: My suggestion isn't really better, it's a bad trick ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer... deleting this... Already upvoted yours...